# Can't connect to salesforce with force plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I'm using eclipse 4.6.3 with Force.com IDE 38.0.0.201701101558.  When I enter my credentials in project properties it says

```
com.salesforce.ide.core.remote.ForceConnectionException: Unable to create connection to server 'test.salesforce.com':

SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

    at com.salesforce.ide.core.internal.utils.ForceExceptionUtils.handleConnectionException(ForceExceptionUtils.java:74)
```

It is a sandbox environment and I have that option selected in project properties.  I'm able to get an OAuth token from test.salesforce.com with the same 
credentials from the same laptop and IP address. I don't see any login attempts in login history when I try to connect.  One of my coworkers has the same versions and is able to connect to salesforce. I've also tried downgrading to eclipse 4.5.2 and had the same problem.  I'm using

```
https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45
```

to download the plugin.  Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Here's something of a troubleshooting guess. If your org uses trusted IP ranges, make certain your IP range is included. Since you're using OAuth, check your user profile in the Sandbox which will have your email address and user name set with the name the sandbox is appended with which could affect your ability to login. Check the OAuth setup as well.